# RSpec using old attribute fields for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I made a mistake in the spelling of a model attribute name so I rolled back the changes and updated the model name to be the correct one. However, RSpec is still using the old model attribute name for some reason?

heres the spec:

```
....
  let(:message_client) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:contact_message, client_id: alice.id) }

  it "should redirect to the user edit page if a user is signed in" do
    sign_in alice
    post :create, contact_message: message_client
    expect(response).to redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
  end
```

Heres the FactoryGirl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact_message do
    contact_subject "Pay me"
    contact_body "I didn't recieve my latest payment"
  end
end
```

Heres the schema extract:

```
create_table "contact_messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "contact_subject"
    t.text     "contact_body"
    t.integer  "freelancer_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

And here's the error:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create, contact_message: message_client
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `contact_subject=' for #<ContactMessage:0x007fe9840b5e08>
```

And when I chuck a binding.pry in my controller create action and put in `ContactMessage` this is what is returned:

```
     3: def create
     4:   @message = current_freelancer.contact_messages.build(contact_message_params) if current_freelancer
 =>  5:   binding.pry
     6:   @message = current_user.contact_messages.build(contact_message_params) if current_user
     7: 
     8:   if @message.save
     9:     flash[:notice] = "Message Recieved"
    10:     redirect_to edit_freelancer_registration_path if current_freelancer
    11:     redirect_to edit_user_registration_path if current_user
    12:   else
    13:     redirect_to edit_freelancer_registration_path if current_freelancer
    14:     redirect_to edit_user_registration_path if current_user
    15:   end
    16: end

[1] pry(#<ContactMessagesController>)> ContactMessage
=> ContactMessage(id: integer, messge_subject: string, message_body: text, freelancer_id: integer, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

If you look down the bottom there it is still using the old fields for the model (messge_subject). Any ideas why it is doing this? I've tried restarting my comp and terminal to no avail.

Comment: Did you also roll back your test database?

Comment: Oops I didn't. How do I do that? @spickermann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common oversight that RSpec uses another database than your development server.

If you have to rollback a migration you will have to rollback that migration in your test environment too:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm. Never run into this issue before but glad I know how to solve it now!

Answer (score 1):

To update your test database try

```
rake db:test:prepare
```